# Send an e-mail using custom SMTP settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I would like to send an e-mail from rails via SMTP using credentials provided via some web form. So rather than configuring the mailer at startup using something like this:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => address,
  :domain               => domain,
  :user_name            => user_name,
  :password             => password,
}
```

and then sending the mail using `UserMailer.send_mail(user).deliver_now`

I would like to set the smtp setting only for one *single* mail based on variables obtained from the database.

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.smtp_settings = {
  :address => ‘smtp.gmail.com’, :port => 587,
  :domain => ‘gmail.com’,
  :authentication => ‘plain’,
  :user_name => <email_username>,
  :password => <email_password>,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

 send_mail(option, data) 

     email.delivery_method.settings.merge!({:address => 
     Email.email_address, :port => Email.email_port, :domain => 
     Email.email_domain, :user_name =>Email.email_username, :password => Email.email_password, :enable_starttls_auto => true}) 
     email.deliver_now 
 end

end
```

try something like